# Creating a websocket with ngrok

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, websocket, ip-address, ngrok

I am using ngrok to tunnel to my ASP.NET core application. I am using Fleck to try and create a websocket connection between my application (server side) and an external API (client side). The problem is, the API requires a URL (ws://mysite.com/socket) that it will request a websocket connection from, however, the `WebSocketServer(ip)` object creates a websocket on a certain IP address and port. Can I tell the API to try and establish a connection with `ws://5f1ce6fe.ngrok.io`? Also, how do I find the IP address/port combination using ngrok that I will use to open the appropriate websocket on my server so that it accepts a websocket request at `ws://5f1ce6fe.ngrok.io`?

Thanks